# Passive Installation with WIX Toolset - Error 2726: Action not found: WelcomeDlg

Tags: visual-studio-2012, wix, wix3.8

I created a WIX-Setup for my webservices with the help of this tutorial:
http://blogs.planetsoftware.com.au/paul/archive/2011/02/20/creating-a-web-application-installer-with-wix-3.5-and-visual.aspx

I used Visual Studio 2012 and Wix 3.8. The msi is started by a Wix Bootstrapper.

The Installation works perfectly, all default-propertys are set right and on update they are read from the registry.

My problem is that the installation is aborted when I use the "/passive" parameter. The dialogs can't be loaded and the propertys aren't set anymore. Here are the logs:

Error using the /passive parameter:

```
MSI (c) (D4:FC) [12:08:11:108]: Doing action: WelcomeDlg
Aktion 12:08:11: WelcomeDlg. 
Aktion gestartet um 12:08:11: WelcomeDlg.
DEBUG: Error 2726:  Action not found: WelcomeDlg
Bei der Installation dieses Pakets ist ein unerwarteter Fehler aufgetreten. Es liegt eventuell ein das Paket betreffendes Problem vor. Der Fehlercode ist 2726. Argumente: WelcomeDlg, , 
Aktion beendet um 12:08:11: WelcomeDlg. Rückgabewert 0.
MSI (c) (D4:FC) [12:08:11:108]: Doing action: ProgressDlg
Aktion 12:08:11: ProgressDlg. 
Aktion gestartet um 12:08:11: ProgressDlg.
```

Log without any parameters:

```
MSI (c) (60:F8) [12:15:51:852]: Doing action: WelcomeDlg
Aktion 12:15:51: WelcomeDlg. 
Aktion gestartet um 12:15:51: WelcomeDlg.
Aktion 12:15:51: WelcomeDlg. Dialog created
MSI (c) (60:FC) [12:15:51:914]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: _RemoveFilePath 
MSI (c) (60:FC) [12:15:52:008]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying CostingComplete property. Its current value is '0'. Its new value: '1'.
MSI (c) (60:FC) [12:15:52:024]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: BindImage 
MSI (c) (60:FC) [12:15:52:024]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ProgId 
MSI (c) (60:FC) [12:15:52:024]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: PublishComponent 
MSI (c) (60:FC) [12:15:52:024]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: SelfReg 
MSI (c) (60:FC) [12:15:52:024]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Extension 
MSI (c) (60:FC) [12:15:52:024]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Font 
MSI (c) (60:FC) [12:15:52:024]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Shortcut 
MSI (c) (60:FC) [12:15:52:024]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Class 
MSI (c) (60:FC) [12:15:52:024]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: TypeLib 
MSI (c) (60:FC) [12:15:52:074]: Note: 1: 2727 2:  
Information 2898.For WixUI_Font_Title textstyle, the system created a 'Tahoma' font, in 0 character set, of 14 pixels height.
Aktion 12:15:55: LicenseAgreementDlg. Dialog created
MSI (c) (60:0C) [12:15:56:228]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding LicenseAccepted property. Its value is '1'.
Aktion 12:15:56: InstallationAddress. Dialog created
MSI (c) (60:0C) [12:15:57:808]: Doing action: UpdatePropsWithSelectedWebSite
Aktion 12:15:57: UpdatePropsWithSelectedWebSite. 
Aktion gestartet um 12:15:57: UpdatePropsWithSelectedWebSite.
MSI (c) (60:8C) [12:15:57:808]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\MSI4304.tmp, Entrypoint: UpdatePropsWithSelectedWebSite
MSI (c) (60!90) [12:15:58:239]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding WEBSITE_ID property. Its value is '1'.
MSI (c) (60!90) [12:15:58:239]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding WEBSITE_DESCRIPTION property. Its value is 'Default Web Site'.
MSI (c) (60!90) [12:15:58:239]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding WEBSITE_PATH property. Its value is 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot'.
MSI (c) (60!90) [12:15:58:239]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding DIRECTORY property. Its value is 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LANDWEHR Webservices'.
MSI (c) (60!90) [12:15:58:239]: Doing action: SetApplicationRootDirectory
MSI (c) (60!90) [12:15:58:239]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying INSTALLLOCATION property. Its current value is 'C:\LANDWEHR Webservices\'. Its new value: 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LANDWEHR Webservices\'.
MSI (c) (60!90) [12:15:58:239]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying INSTALLLOCATION.Tools property. Its current value is 'C:\LANDWEHR Webservices\Tools\'. Its new value: 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LANDWEHR Webservices\Tools\'.
MSI (c) (60!90) [12:15:58:239]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying INSTALLLOCATION.InstallationsTest property. Its current value is 'C:\LANDWEHR Webservices\Tools\InstallationsTest\'. Its new value: 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LANDWEHR Webservices\Tools\InstallationsTest\'.
MSI (c) (60!90) [12:15:58:239]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying INSTALLLOCATION.Tools.DatenbankAdministrator property. Its current value is 'C:\LANDWEHR Webservices\Tools\DatenbankAdministrator\'. Its new value: 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LANDWEHR Webservices\Tools\DatenbankAdministrator\'.
MSI (c) (60!90) [12:15:58:239]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying INSTALLLOCATION.Aliase property. Its current value is 'C:\LANDWEHR Webservices\Aliase\'. Its new value: 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LANDWEHR Webservices\Aliase\'.
MSI (c) (60!90) [12:15:58:239]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying INSTALLLOCATION.Databases property. Its current value is 'C:\LANDWEHR Webservices\Databases\'. Its new value: 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LANDWEHR Webservices\Databases\'.
MSI (c) (60!90) [12:15:58:239]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying INSTALLLOCATION.L2App property. Its current value is 'C:\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.L2App\'. Its new value: 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.L2App\'.
MSI (c) (60!90) [12:15:58:239]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying INSTALLLOCATION.Zeiterfassung property. Its current value is 'C:\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.Zeiterfassung\'. Its new value: 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.Zeiterfassung\'.
MSI (c) (60!90) [12:15:58:255]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying dir428A913842499AD95CE10212AF166D62 property. Its current value is 'C:\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.Zeiterfassung\bin\'. Its new value: 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.Zeiterfassung\bin\'.
MSI (c) (60!90) [12:15:58:255]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying INSTALLLOCATION.Vorgang property. Its current value is 'C:\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.Vorgang\'. Its new value: 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.Vorgang\'.
MSI (c) (60!90) [12:15:58:255]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying dir04CC18032BDD597CD8DB5D70CBEE3B01 property. Its current value is 'C:\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.Vorgang\bin\'. Its new value: 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.Vorgang\bin\'.
MSI (c) (60!90) [12:15:58:255]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying INSTALLLOCATION.Verbindungstest property. Its current value is 'C:\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.Verbindungstest\'. Its new value: 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.Verbindungstest\'.
MSI (c) (60!90) [12:15:58:255]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying dirF491182A3D558B5FCB7BF48A7A3F8205 property. Its current value is 'C:\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.Verbindungstest\bin\'. Its new value: 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.Verbindungstest\bin\'.
MSI (c) (60!90) [12:15:58:255]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying INSTALLLOCATION.Stammdaten property. Its current value is 'C:\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.Stammdaten\'. Its new value: 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.Stammdaten\'.
MSI (c) (60!90) [12:15:58:271]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying dirA0DC6D6D78D458400161FCD675D25D28 property. Its current value is 'C:\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.Stammdaten\bin\'. Its new value: 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.Stammdaten\bin\'.
MSI (c) (60!90) [12:15:58:271]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying INSTALLLOCATION.Postbox property. Its current value is 'C:\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.Postbox\'. Its new value: 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.Postbox\'.
MSI (c) (60!90) [12:15:58:271]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying dir8FAA84BBF5D5B62387EBC3141A61BBCF property. Its current value is 'C:\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.Postbox\bin\'. Its new value: 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.Postbox\bin\'.
MSI (c) (60!90) [12:15:58:271]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying INSTALLLOCATION.Personal property. Its current value is 'C:\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.Personal\'. Its new value: 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.Personal\'.
MSI (c) (60!90) [12:15:58:271]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying dir8E07B3994D9E0D999F64CD4ECD3A55F8 property. Its current value is 'C:\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.Personal\bin\'. Its new value: 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.Personal\bin\'.
MSI (c) (60!90) [12:15:58:271]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying INSTALLLOCATION.Option property. Its current value is 'C:\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.Option\'. Its new value: 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.Option\'.
MSI (c) (60!90) [12:15:58:286]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying dir0D8C2FB3A95E261B35BFB41C70E74571 property. Its current value is 'C:\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.Option\bin\'. Its new value: 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.Option\bin\'.
MSI (c) (60!90) [12:15:58:286]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying INSTALLLOCATION.NotizWrite property. Its current value is 'C:\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.NotizWrite\'. Its new value: 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.NotizWrite\'.
MSI (c) (60!90) [12:15:58:286]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying dir638AAEAD4EF5FE7BB3E4F25BC1F427D0 property. Its current value is 'C:\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.NotizWrite\bin\'. Its new value: 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.NotizWrite\bin\'.
MSI (c) (60!90) [12:15:58:286]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying INSTALLLOCATION.Notiz property. Its current value is 'C:\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.Notiz\'. Its new value: 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.Notiz\'.
MSI (c) (60!90) [12:15:58:286]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying dirEFB6E749A7C3768756B7617BC441F8EE property. Its current value is 'C:\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.Notiz\bin\'. Its new value: 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.Notiz\bin\'.
MSI (c) (60!90) [12:15:58:286]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying INSTALLLOCATION.NotificationCount property. Its current value is 'C:\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.NotificationCount\'. Its new value: 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.NotificationCount\'.
MSI (c) (60!90) [12:15:58:302]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying dirF09B09AAFF8C1607C1778881AB2B4A71 property. Its current value is 'C:\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.NotificationCount\bin\'. Its new value: 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.NotificationCount\bin\'.
MSI (c) (60!90) [12:15:58:302]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying INSTALLLOCATION.MobileSystem property. Its current value is 'C:\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.MobileSystem\'. Its new value: 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.MobileSystem\'.
MSI (c) (60!90) [12:15:58:302]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying dirBC2B48C2883BEA3904DBDFDF4C1878B0 property. Its current value is 'C:\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.MobileSystem\bin\'. Its new value: 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.MobileSystem\bin\'.
MSI (c) (60!90) [12:15:58:302]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying INSTALLLOCATION.Kunde property. Its current value is 'C:\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.Kunde\'. Its new value: 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.Kunde\'.
MSI (c) (60!90) [12:15:58:317]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying dir5A042499AC06A7AF2FCDCD04E0B57ED5 property. Its current value is 'C:\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.Kunde\bin\'. Its new value: 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.Kunde\bin\'.
MSI (c) (60!90) [12:15:58:317]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying INSTALLLOCATION.Kontakt property. Its current value is 'C:\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.Kontakt\'. Its new value: 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.Kontakt\'.
MSI (c) (60!90) [12:15:58:317]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying dirF74EF7A621979E27894A991152AB1D85 property. Its current value is 'C:\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.Kontakt\bin\'. Its new value: 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.Kontakt\bin\'.
MSI (c) (60!90) [12:15:58:317]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying INSTALLLOCATION.DateiUpload property. Its current value is 'C:\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.DateiUpload\'. Its new value: 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.DateiUpload\'.
MSI (c) (60!90) [12:15:58:317]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying dirF57F8AD38681C93BC178CD0840168033 property. Its current value is 'C:\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.DateiUpload\bin\'. Its new value: 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.DateiUpload\bin\'.
MSI (c) (60!90) [12:15:58:317]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying INSTALLLOCATION.Datei property. Its current value is 'C:\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.Datei\'. Its new value: 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.Datei\'.
MSI (c) (60!90) [12:15:58:317]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying dirE11550ADA7189003514FBBE63B5AF165 property. Its current value is 'C:\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.Datei\bin\'. Its new value: 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.Datei\bin\'.
MSI (c) (60!90) [12:15:58:317]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying INSTALLLOCATION.Versionswechsel property. Its current value is 'C:\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.Versionswechsel\'. Its new value: 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.Versionswechsel\'.
MSI (c) (60!90) [12:15:58:317]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying dir1B45886473DF7AC164930CFEEE0DB3F8 property. Its current value is 'C:\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.Versionswechsel\bin\'. Its new value: 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.Versionswechsel\bin\'.
MSI (c) (60!90) [12:15:58:317]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying INSTALLLOCATION.DataStorage property. Its current value is 'C:\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.DataStorage\'. Its new value: 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.DataStorage\'.
MSI (c) (60!90) [12:15:58:317]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying dir3ACFA82854F640A923237DE5B29C5CA3 property. Its current value is 'C:\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.DataStorage\bin\'. Its new value: 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.DataStorage\bin\'.
MSI (c) (60!90) [12:15:58:317]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying INSTALLLOCATION.CommandStorage property. Its current value is 'C:\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.CommandStorage\'. Its new value: 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.CommandStorage\'.
MSI (c) (60!90) [12:15:58:333]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying dir19D89E1E9D25C3035155C7C8E522E594 property. Its current value is 'C:\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.CommandStorage\bin\'. Its new value: 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.CommandStorage\bin\'.
MSI (c) (60!90) [12:15:58:333]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying INSTALLLOCATION.Berechtigung property. Its current value is 'C:\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.Berechtigung\'. Its new value: 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.Berechtigung\'.
MSI (c) (60!90) [12:15:58:333]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying dir8041ECB23E27C1BFE77DBF9D5F3643AF property. Its current value is 'C:\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.Berechtigung\bin\'. Its new value: 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.Berechtigung\bin\'.
MSI (c) (60!90) [12:15:58:333]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying INSTALLLOCATION.Auswertung property. Its current value is 'C:\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.Auswertung\'. Its new value: 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.Auswertung\'.
MSI (c) (60!90) [12:15:58:333]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying dirB59D26B9AF347FE298EC58C9BE47C5D0 property. Its current value is 'C:\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.Auswertung\bin\'. Its new value: 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.Auswertung\bin\'.
MSI (c) (60!90) [12:15:58:333]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying INSTALLLOCATION.AuthMapper property. Its current value is 'C:\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.AuthMapper\'. Its new value: 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.AuthMapper\'.
MSI (c) (60!90) [12:15:58:333]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying dirFBFBC9EE83DD1D072E9D09468C2DD799 property. Its current value is 'C:\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.AuthMapper\Service References\'. Its new value: 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.AuthMapper\Service References\'.
MSI (c) (60!90) [12:15:58:333]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying dir8FBB835386D5528023541630DC87C12C property. Its current value is 'C:\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.AuthMapper\Service References\RefAuthService\'. Its new value: 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.AuthMapper\Service References\RefAuthService\'.
MSI (c) (60!90) [12:15:58:333]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying dir08C7BD36AE973D83AD5A42B74C66E348 property. Its current value is 'C:\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.AuthMapper\Properties\'. Its new value: 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.AuthMapper\Properties\'.
MSI (c) (60!90) [12:15:58:333]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying dir5BE1C953B92E4166540EEC5335EB1D8B property. Its current value is 'C:\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.AuthMapper\Properties\DataSources\'. Its new value: 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.AuthMapper\Properties\DataSources\'.
MSI (c) (60!90) [12:15:58:333]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying dir3324CF78F6B5411435451B5E8AE3FA9E property. Its current value is 'C:\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.AuthMapper\bin\'. Its new value: 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.AuthMapper\bin\'.
MSI (c) (60!90) [12:15:58:333]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying INSTALLLOCATION.Auth property. Its current value is 'C:\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.Auth\'. Its new value: 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.Auth\'.
MSI (c) (60!90) [12:15:58:333]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying dirAAC07DD7E91AFCCD2AADA8D9C224FAEC property. Its current value is 'C:\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.Auth\bin\'. Its new value: 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LANDWEHR Webservices\Service.Auth\bin\'.
MSI (c) (60!90) [12:15:58:333]: Note: 1: 2727 2:  
Aktion beendet um 12:15:58: UpdatePropsWithSelectedWebSite. Rückgabewert 1.
Aktion 12:15:58: InstallDirDlg. Dialog created
MSI (c) (60:0C) [12:15:59:568]: Doing action: WixUIValidatePath
Aktion 12:15:59: WixUIValidatePath. 
Aktion gestartet um 12:15:59: WixUIValidatePath.
MSI (c) (60:54) [12:15:59:568]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\MSI49DB.tmp, Entrypoint: ValidatePath
MSI (c) (60!F0) [12:15:59:568]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding WIXUI_INSTALLDIR_VALID property. Its value is '1'.
Aktion beendet um 12:15:59: WixUIValidatePath. Rückgabewert 1.
Aktion 12:15:59: VerifyReadyDlg. Dialog created
MSI (c) (60:0C) [12:16:00:099]: Note: 1: 2727 2:  
Aktion beendet um 12:16:00: WelcomeDlg. Rückgabewert 1.
MSI (c) (60:F8) [12:16:00:383]: Doing action: ProgressDlg
Aktion 12:16:00: ProgressDlg.
```

I thought the "/passive" parameter would just click "next" in every dialog... Did I miss anything?

Here is the source of the UI with the "WelcomeDlg":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Fragment>
    <WixVariable Id="WixUIBannerBmp" Value="banner.jpg" />
    <WixVariable Id="WixUIDialogBmp" Value="dialog.jpg" />
    <WixVariable Id="WixUILicenseRtf" Value="End User License Agreement.rtf" />

    <UI Id="WixUI_WebUI">
      <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Normal" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="8" />
      <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Bigger" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="12" />
      <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Title" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="9" Bold="yes" />

      <Property Id="DefaultUIFont" Value="WixUI_Font_Normal" />
      <Property Id="WixUI_Mode" Value="InstallDir" />

      <DialogRef Id="BrowseDlg" />
      <DialogRef Id="DiskCostDlg" />
      <DialogRef Id="ErrorDlg" />
      <DialogRef Id="FatalError" />
      <DialogRef Id="FilesInUse" />
      <DialogRef Id="MsiRMFilesInUse" />
      <DialogRef Id="PrepareDlg" />
      <DialogRef Id="ProgressDlg" />
      <DialogRef Id="ResumeDlg" />
      <DialogRef Id="UserExit" />

      <Publish Dialog="BrowseDlg" Control="OK" Event="DoAction"
               Value="WixUIValidatePath" Order="3">1</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="BrowseDlg" Control="OK" Event="SpawnDialog"
               Value="InvalidDirDlg" Order="4"><![CDATA[WIXUI_INSTALLDIR_VALID<>"1"]]></Publish>

      <Publish Dialog="ExitDialog" Control="Finish" Event="EndDialog"
               Value="Return" Order="999">1</Publish>

      <Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog"
               Value="LicenseAgreementDlg">NOT Installed</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog"
               Value="VerifyReadyDlg">Installed AND PATCH</Publish>

      <Publish Dialog="LicenseAgreementDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog"
               Value="WelcomeDlg">1</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="LicenseAgreementDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog"
               Value="InstallationAddress">LicenseAccepted = "1"</Publish>

      <!-- Custom: Select existing web site, and specify VD name -->
      <Publish Dialog="InstallationAddress" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog"
               Value="LicenseAgreementDlg" Order="1">1</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="InstallationAddress" Control="Next" Event="DoAction"
               Value="UpdatePropsWithSelectedWebSite" Order="1">1</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="InstallationAddress" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog"
               Value="InstallDirDlg" Order="2">1</Publish>

      <!-- Changed InstallDirDlg back button to navigate to InstallationAddress -->
      <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog"
               Value="InstallationAddress">1</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="SetTargetPath"
               Value="[WIXUI_INSTALLDIR]" Order="1">1</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="DoAction"
               Value="WixUIValidatePath" Order="2">NOT WIXUI_DONTVALIDATEPATH</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="SpawnDialog"
               Value="InvalidDirDlg" Order="3"
               ><![CDATA[NOT WIXUI_DONTVALIDATEPATH AND WIXUI_INSTALLDIR_VALID<>"1"]]></Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog"
               Value="VerifyReadyDlg" Order="4"
               >WIXUI_DONTVALIDATEPATH OR WIXUI_INSTALLDIR_VALID="1"</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="ChangeFolder" Property="_BrowseProperty"
               Value="[WIXUI_INSTALLDIR]" Order="1">1</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="ChangeFolder" Event="SpawnDialog"
               Value="BrowseDlg" Order="2">1</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog"
               Value="InstallDirDlg" Order="1">NOT Installed</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog"
               Value="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Order="2">Installed AND NOT PATCH</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog"
               Value="WelcomeDlg" Order="2">Installed AND PATCH</Publish>

      <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceWelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog"
               Value="MaintenanceTypeDlg">1</Publish>

      <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="RepairButton" Event="NewDialog"
               Value="VerifyReadyDlg">1</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="RemoveButton" Event="NewDialog"
               Value="VerifyReadyDlg">1</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog"
               Value="MaintenanceWelcomeDlg">1</Publish>

      <Property Id="ARPNOMODIFY" Value="1" />
    </UI>

    <UIRef Id="WixUI_Common" />
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Here is a Link to the full log:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzpZiQoqaVUicHBabjdRNGRhWm8/edit?usp=sharing

And the (working) log without the "/passive" parameter:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzpZiQoqaVUiVU5JUC1xYkwzc2M/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: More of the failing log might be useful to see what's happening just before the failure, and more of the command line.  It seems unlikely, but if you are some other sequence (such as advertise) that's where the dialog might be missing, just to rule out certain things. Passive shouldn't ordinarily show anything apart from some progress with no Cancel option. And you're sure the product isn't already installed and you're doing an inadvertent maintenance operation?

Comment: Full Command line: "Setup.exe /passive /log log.log" I will post the full log in the original post. I'm testing on a clean virtual machine (Win 8 Prof 64bit) so there aren't any old installations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The log you supplied didn't appear to have any issues with a welcomne dialog, it's just a failed install because of the stuff below, and it rolled back.

MSI (s) (BC:F8) [11:59:59:959]: Executing op: CustomActionSchedule(Action=WriteIIS7ConfigChanges,ActionType=11265,Source=BinaryData,Target=**********,CustomActionData=**********)

MSI (s) (BC:78) [11:59:59:990]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Windows\Installer\MSICABD.tmp, Entrypoint: WriteIIS7ConfigChanges
WriteIIS7ConfigChanges:  Error 0x80070002: Site not found for create application
WriteIIS7ConfigChanges:  Error 0x80070002: Failed to configure IIS application.
WriteIIS7ConfigChanges:  Error 0x80070002: WriteIIS7ConfigChanges Failed.
CustomAction WriteIIS7ConfigChanges returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
Aktion beendet um 12:00:10: InstallFinalize. Rückgabewert 3.

MSI (s) (BC:F8) [12:00:10:600]: Note: 1: 2265 2:  3: -2147287035

MSI (s) (BC:F8) [12:00:10:600]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0

Comment: It's failing because the without the "Welcome" dialog the  "InstallationAddress" dialog is also not loaded and the propertys (Path, Website, etc.) are never set. The question is why are the dialogs fail to load.

Comment: I'm still not sure why the dialogs aren't loaded. My soultion was to create a CustomAction that sets all propertys after CostFinalize (before the dialogs are shown).

Comment: You are using the /passive option, and that means no dialogs will be called. Basically the entire UI sequence is skipped, so if there are properties that are set in the UI sequence they won't be set and you should supply them as public (UPPERCASE) properties on the msiexec command line.